# How can you use a function and pass it a column inside a Google Sheets Query?

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function, google-sheets-query

On Sheet 1, I have data

```
CATEGORY  |  PATIENT  |    DATE    |  AMOUNT
Vision    |  Joe      |  1/1/2016  |   $100
Vision    |  Joe      |  1/2/2016  |   $100
Vision    |  Joe      |  1/3/2016  |   $100
```

On Sheet 2,

```
CATEGORY  |  PATIENT  |  TOTAL 2016  |
Vision    |  Joe      |     $300     |
```

However I don't have this working.
The query I am using in Column C of Sheet 2 is:

```
=QUERY('Sheet'!1:1000, "SELECT SUM(D) WHERE A='"& A2 &"' AND B='"& B2 &"' AND '"&YEAR(C)&"'='2016' label SUM(D) ''")
```

However I am getting an error

```
#NAME?
Unknown range name: 'C'.
```

Why can't I pass the column `C` to the `YEAR` function?

Comment: Because Year needs a cell (ie: C1) as an argument, not a column (ie: just C). anyhow, questions about Google-Sheets are off-topic for SU - voted to migrate to WebApps.

Comment: Oh thanks. So is there some way to use this function in a Query?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using the wrong syntax. Guessing that you want a query to populate a single cell (assumed to be C2), please try:

```
  =QUERY(Sheet1!A1:D1000,"SELECT sum(D) WHERE A='"&A2&"' AND B='"&B2&"' and C >= date '2016-01-01' AND C <= date '2016-12-31' label SUM(D) ''")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the OP didn't just want the sum for the date range solely for "Joe." It seems what is called for here is running a QUERY that first filters the data for only those entries within the date range, and then running a QUERY on that initial QUERY using "GROUP BY":

`=QUERY(QUERY(A:D,"Select A, B, D WHERE C >= date '2016-01-01' and C <= date '2016-12-31' and NOT D = ''"),"Select Col1, Col2, SUM(Col3) GROUP BY Col1, Col2")`

This will produce a new chart with headers, showing totals for each person by category, drawn only from the desired date range. The sums for the date range make having a "Date" column unhelpful, so that won't be part of the newly created chart, just "Category | Patient | Sum Amount."